# MotionLayout - annoying debug error in the log: "no widget for <view id> (<view type>)"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I've been using MotionLayout for a while now, and it's been an absolute delight.

But I've been facing a pollution problem I'd like to know how can I get rid of.

Basically I'm getting bombarded the following kinds of errors in the logs, despite not seeing any issue with my MotionLayout-powered layouts:

```
2020-04-02 23:32:35.709 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1959)no widget for  callLog (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.709 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1967)no widget for  callLog (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.709 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1959)no widget for  spaceTop (android.widget.Space)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1967)no widget for  spaceTop (android.widget.Space)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1959)no widget for  callLogExpanded (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1967)no widget for  callLogExpanded (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1959)no widget for  callLogDeleteIcon (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1967)no widget for  callLogDeleteIcon (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1959)no widget for  guidelineLeft (androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1967)no widget for  guidelineLeft (androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1959)no widget for  callLog (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1967)no widget for  callLog (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1959)no widget for  spaceTop (android.widget.Space)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1967)no widget for  spaceTop (android.widget.Space)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1959)no widget for  callLogExpanded (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView)
2020-04-02 23:32:35.710 12500-12500/cz.nn.calllog E/MotionLayout: .(MotionLayout.java:1967)no widget for  callLogExpanded (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView)
```

Inspecting the `build()` method of `MotionLayout.java` didn't help me much in understanding the corner cases that get to yield these errors. My scenes don't have references to all the children of a given MotionLayout, but only to the children that get animated instead. But this log errors reference both children that are completely defined in the scene (meaning they have `Constraint`s defined for all the `ConstraintSet`s) as well as those children that have no reference because they don't have changes in their constraints (whose definitions I've left out of the scene files precisely because MotionLayout accepts this convenience).

I'm using a `RecyclerView` where each children has a view with an embedded MotionLayout. I'm suspecting having both of them together is somehow yield this issue... can anyone tell me if this is potentially something I should worry about? So far I've been ignoring it since as I said, I see really no impact in the overall functionality of the layouts that rely on this class.

This has all been tested on an emulator running Android 10.

Thank you in advance for any insight you might provide!

Comment: Do you have the solution for this? I found out that if I comment out my `layoutDescription` tag the error stack would go away

Comment: No, I still have the issue. If you are commenting out your `layoutDescription` tag, how are you assigning your `MotionScene` to your `MotionLayout`? Programmatically?

Comment: All children of a MotionLayout are part of all constraintSets. MotionLayout read the Constraint from the layout. (Think of it is the base class for a constraintSet.)
Leaving it out of the MotionScene is a convenient way of saying get it from the layout.
So the constraintSet has all these constraints for Views it cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me just now. The issue was that I was attempting to set a transition state in my fragment using the wrong `MotionLayout` (I also have nested MotionLayouts).

Instead of calling `binding.secondMotionLayout.root.setState(...)`, I was calling `binding.firstMotionLayout.root.setState(...) and attempting to reference the` ConstraintSet`s of the second` MotionLayout`.

Maybe you are doing something similar with your `RecyclerView`? I would make sure to properly reference the `MotionLayout` of each item in your RecyclerView. Depending on how you've implemented it, it would be inside the ViewHolder.